# Where to add Link tags on a page that's got a master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

When I type it here :-

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">

<link href="Skins/SkinCustom/Editor.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</asp:Content>
```

Its says Element Link cannot be nested within div...how am I supposed to link my css files ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a ContentPlaceHolder in your master's `head` tag:

```
<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Then in your content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <link href="Skins/SkinCustom/Editor.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thanks, @bla I was not able to understand where to place the links on the asp page. Now it works like charm.

Answer (score 3):

If your master page does not provide a content placeholder in the `<head>` section *(ed: and you can't edit it)*, you may be out of luck.

Have a look at the master page source and see what other content placeholders are available.